# Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.email'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

```
promise.then(user => {
      var err = "Welcome " + user.email;
      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uuid).set({
        email: user.email
      });
```

error is in 3rd line. don't know why it is showing on this line.

Comment: My guess would be that `user.uuid` is returning `undefined`. Perhaps try `user.uid`

Comment: i mistakenly wrote uuid its uid and still the error is same.

Answer (score 1):

Alter your code as follows:

```
promise.then(user => {
  var err = "Welcome " + user.email;
  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.user.uuid).set({
    email: user.user.email
  });
```

Firebase returns a promise with an object. this object holds the 'user' object inside. So, you need to go inside this object, then call 'user', and then 'email' and also 'uuid' or 'uid'.